# Concurrent modification exception. How to avoid in this scenario?

Tags: java, arraylist, concurrentmodification

Consider the following code:

```
 List tableData = null;
 tableData = new ArrayList(records.size());
 for (Iterator iter = records.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
            Test record = (Test ) iter.next();
            Map rowData = createRowData(record);
            if (rowData != null) {
                // sorted insert
                Date newDate = (Date)       rowData.get(TestModel.TIMESTAMP);
                boolean done = false;
                for (int row = 0; row < tableData.size(); row++) {
                    Map currentRow = (Map) tableData.get(row);
                    Date currentDate = (Date)     currentRow.get(TestModel.TIMESTAMP);
                    if (currentDate.after(newDate)) {
                        tableData.add(row, rowData);
                        done = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
    if (!done) {
                    tableData.add(rowData);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch( Exception e ) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error reading fuel and SMU data", e);
    }
    return tableData;
```

`records` here are `new Vector()` which is being initialized inbetween.

As the ArrayList has an argument of int capacity. How can I use `CopyOnWriteArrayList`in this scenario?

```
`STACKTRACE:
    at com.mincom.explorer.uif.AbstractRequestHandler.handleException(AbstractRequestHandler.java:255)
    at com.mincom.explorer.uif.AbstractRequestHandler.readData(AbstractRequestHandler.java:137)
    at com.mincom.jive.service.RequestExecutor$RequestHandlerCommand.mainProcess(RequestExecutor.java:156)
    at com.mincom.util.executor.AbstractCommand.run(AbstractCommand.java:56)
    at com.mincom.util.executor.SimpleExecutor$WorkerThread.run(SimpleExecutor.java:156)
 THROWABLE: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading fuel and SMU data
    at minestar.production.presentation.page.fuel.smu.assistant.*.getEventsUsingFilter(*.java:243)
    at minestar.production.presentation.page.fuel.smu.assistant.*.processReadData(*.java:174)
    at com.mincom.explorer.uif.AbstractRequestHandler.readData(AbstractRequestHandler.java:129)
    at com.mincom.jive.service.RequestExecutor$RequestHandlerCommand.mainProcess(RequestExecutor.java:156)
    at com.mincom.util.executor.AbstractCommand.run(AbstractCommand.java:56)
    at com.mincom.util.executor.SimpleExecutor$WorkerThread.run(SimpleExecutor.java:156)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at *.production.presentation.page.fuel.smu.assistant.*.getEventsUsingFilter(*.java:222)
    ... 5 more`
```

I have modified the piece of code again. PLease have a look.

Comment: Start by explaining exactly what throws the exception.

Comment: This question is totally vague and unclear. Please provide a **complete** example source as well as a **full** exception stacktrace of the `ConcurrentModificationException` that we can try and replicate in order to help you accurately.

Comment: Your stacktrace is **not complete**. Can you post the **full** stacktrace as I requested? How does `*.java` help in this context?

Comment: What line of the code you have posted throws the exception? Please, try to put yourself into the shoes of those looking to help you. Don't just post random snippets of code and stacktrace, make a clear problem statement and accompany with diagnostic data.

Comment: I cannot paste the full stacktrace. Its a production snippet.

Comment: Don't paste the literal stack trace from your production, post the aspects relevant for diagnostics. Nobody cares about the names of your classes and methods.

Comment: use iterator for tableData as well !

Comment: @Sikorski you cannot add an item using an `Iterator`, only `remove()`.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi why is there an add method then in API ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#add%28E%29

Comment: @Sikorski, `ArrayList` **never** returns a `ListIterator` on `iterator()` method call. It has its own internal `Iterator` called `Itr`. You can always try `Iterator itr = new ArrayList().iterator(); System.out.println((list instanceof ListIterator));`. You'll see it displays the value as `false`.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi use the listIterator method then :)

Comment: I'm not the one who initiated this question @Sikorski.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the List, you're working with.

There are two ways to get rid of this. One is, create a copy of your actual list, and iterate over this new list, but modify the old one.

```
List copy = copyOf(myArrayList);
for(item : copy){
     //do stuff
     //addon original list
     myArrayList.add(item);
}
```

The second is, iterate backwards over your list.

```
for(int i = list.size()-1; i >=0; i--){
    //add or remove or do stuff here
}
```

The second solution won't work for you, because you are adding your item on a specific index. But if you just add/remove the current grabbed item, this would be fine, too

Note, this is pseudo code

Comment: There is no evidence in the code that OP is doing this.

Comment: `tableData = new ArrayList..... ` -> `for(int row = 0; row < tableData.size...` -> `tableData.add...`

Comment: Indeed, I overlooked the inner loop.

Comment: However, the line which OP indicated is the *outer* for-loop header.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over array list and then modifying it by adding   `tableData.add(row, rowData);` data at specific index i.e modifying size of list.

I think it's leading `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` exception, better way create another array list and add content into it.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding data into the `List` while iterating through it:

```
for (int row = 0; row < tableData.size(); row++) {
    Map currentRow = (Map) tableData.get(row);
    Date currentDate = (Date)     currentRow.get(TestModel.TIMESTAMP);
    if (currentDate.after(newDate)) {
        tableData.add(row, rowData);
        done = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

This is the reason why you're getting a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

[`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) won't solve your problem: I would suggest to clone your `tableData` and while iterating through your original `tableData`, add new records in the `clonedTableData` and later assign `tableData` to "equal" `clonedtableData`. *Note:* It can be an expensive exercise.

The reason of why I said that "`CopyOnWriteArrayList` won't solve your problem" is based on it's design:

> This array never changes during the lifetime of the iterator, so
>   interference is impossible and the iterator is guaranteed not to throw
>   `ConcurrentModificationException`. The iterator will not reflect
>   additions, removals, or changes to the list since the iterator was
>   created. Element-changing operations on iterators themselves (remove,
>   set, and add) are not supported. These methods throw
>   `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add data to the list while you are iterating though it.

Comment: Kind of you, but you aren’t really contributing anything that isn’t already in the other answer. I don’t think there’s any need to repeat.